# Register content observer for appwidgets on boot

Tags: android, boot, reboot, contentobserver, android-appwidget

I am registering a `ContentObserver` when the user adds my appwidget to the home screen. The intended behavior is that changes to the underlying data in my `ContentProvider` will trigger my appwidget to update. The problem is if the user then reboots the device, I no longer have a `ContentObserver` registered.

Android's AppWidget framework appears to provide no hooks to do any sort of setups after the device boots, so I can't register another `ContentObserver` on the data. The only solution I can think of is creating a BroadcastReceiver, registered in the manifest, that receives the BOOT_COMPLETED action. I was hoping not to have to do this though.

Are there any ways to register a ContentObserver (or do any other setup related to AppWidgets) after boot so that existing appwidgets will continue to function properly across device reboots? (If possible, is there a sample of this somewhere?)

**EDIT**:

It appears after boot my AppWidgetProvider is being called, and the onEnabled and onUpdate callbacks both occur. It starts my AppWidgetService and creates a RemoteViewsFactory -- at which point I should have a ContentObserver registered.

For whatever reason though, the ContentObserver is not firing when the data in my ContentProvider changes. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

This answer is a bit outdated. Making a Service solely for holding a ContentObserver is a bit heavy handed and users might find it strange that an app is keeping a service around without understanding why. Also the OS can terminate the Service, which leaves you without a ContentObserver.

It's probably better to force refresh your appwidgets yourself when you data changes. Google does this as well in their iosched app:

```
// Widgets can't register content observers so we refresh widgets separately.
context.sendBroadcast(ScheduleWidgetProvider.getRefreshBroadcastIntent(context, false));
```

Source: [ScheduleProvider](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/provider/ScheduleProvider.java#L573) [ScheduleWidgetProvider](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/appwidget/ScheduleWidgetProvider.java#L49)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I've solved my own problem by creating a new Service class. I start the service in my AppWidgetProvider's `onEnabled()` callback and stop the service in the `onDisabled()` callback. The content observer is registered in the Service's `onCreate()` and unregistered in `onDestroy`.

This approach lets all my appwidgets be updated when the underlying data changes and works through device reboot.

Comment: How do you create your Service? Could you provide some code of it? I'm mostly interested in configuration as I'm looking for way to register `ContentObserver` reliably.

Comment: This question is a bit outdated. It's not worth having a service running, and the service can be terminated by the OS. It's probably better to force refresh your widgets when your data changes.

Comment: I know it is not so efficient to keep service running, but any way of registering `ContentObserver` I tried failed. Each time my `ContentObserver` was just unregistered by OS and I couldn't determine when and why. The best solutions so far stopped working after night. So now I'm testing approach from original answer. Approach from `ScheduleWidgetProvider` is good for refresh button, but I need reliable way for instant updates.